# "copy and paste" python program

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, gif

I'm currently trying to write a program that reads a GIF file, displays its image on the screen, then allows the user to select a rectangular portion of the image to "copy and paste", AKA to then copy the image within the rectangle and then save the result as a new GIF file. I've gotten pretty far with it, but every time I think I've figured it out is seems that a new error pops up!

```
# CopyAndPaste.py

# This program is designed to read a GIF file, display its image on the screen, allows the user to
# select a rectangular portion of the image to copy and paste, and then save the result as a new GIF file

import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import base64

root = Tk()

def action(canvas):
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xaxis)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", yaxis)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", box)

def xaxis(event):
    global x1, y1
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    print (x1, y1)

def yaxis(event):
    global x2, y2
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    print (x2, y2)

def box(event):
    photo = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
    yaxis(event)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    for x in range(x1, x2):
        for y in range(y1, y2):
            r,g,b = getRGB(photo, x, y)
            newImage(r, g, b, x, y)

def getRGB(photo, x, y):
    value = photo.get(x, y)
    return tuple(map(int, value.split(" ")))

def newImage(r, g, b, x, y):
    picture = PhotoImage(width=x, height=y)
    picture.put("#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b), (x,y))
    picture.write('new_image.gif', format='gif')

canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=250)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
photo = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=NW)
canvas.config(cursor='cross')
action(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please try to split up your question and get a little more in detail. Currently you are asking for a complete tool, which isn't in topic of this page and makes people hard to help

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you create a new `PhotoImage` for each pixel! Instead, create the `PhotoImage` once and just add the pixels in the double-`for`-loop.

```
def box(event):
    yaxis(event)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    picture = PhotoImage(width=(x2-x1), height=(y2-y1))
    for x in range(x1, x2):
        for y in range(y1, y2):
            r, g, b = photo.get(x, y)
            picture.put("#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b), (x-x1, y-y1))
    picture.write('new_image.gif', format='gif')
```

Also, the line `tuple(map(int, value.split(" ")))` in your `getRGB` function is wrong, as `value` is already the tuple you want to create, not a string.<sup>1)</sup> As you can see, I just 'inlined' that part directly into the `box` function. Another problem was that you wrote the copied pixels to `x` and `y`, but you have to write them to `x-x1` and `y-y1` instead.

**Update 1:** <sup>1)</sup> It seems like the return value of `PhotoImage.get` depends on the version of Python/Tkinter you are using. In some versions, it returns a tuple, like `(41, 68, 151)`, and in others, a string, like `u'41 68 151'`.

**Update 2:** As pointed out by @Oblivion, you can in fact just use the `from_coords` parameter of `PhotoImage.write` to specify the region of the picture to be saved to file. With this, the `box` function can be simplified as

```
def box(event):
    yaxis(event)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    photo.write('new_image.gif', format='gif', from_coords=[x1, y1, x2, y2])
```

Comment: photo.write('savetest.gif', format='gif', from_coords=[x1,y1,x2,y2]) should be sufficient to save the selected region.

Comment: @Oblivion Thanks, I did not know this. Added it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import base64

root = Tk()

def action(canvas):
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xaxis)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", yaxis)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", box)

def xaxis(event):
    global x1, y1
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    print (x1, y1)

def yaxis(event):
    global x2, y2
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    print (x2, y2)

def box(event, photo):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    new_photo = copy_photo(photo, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    new_photo.write('new_image.gif', format='gif')

def copy_photo(photo, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    new_photo = PhotoImage(width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
    for x in range(photo.width()):
        for y in range(photo.height()):
            if x1 <= x < x2 and y1 <= y < y2:
                r,g,b = getRGB(photo, x, y)
                new_photo.put("#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b), (x,y))
            else:
                new_photo.put(photo.get(x, y), (x,y))
    return new_photo

def getRGB(photo, x, y):
    value = photo.get(x, y)
    return tuple(map(int, value.split(" ")))

canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=250)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
photo = PhotoImage(file="picture.gif")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=NW)
canvas.config(cursor='cross')
action(canvas)

enter code here

canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).